# Mongodb container doesn't create default database

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I have the following docker-compose

```
  mongo:
    image: mongodb/mongodb-community-server
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./db/mongo
        target: /data/db
    env_file: .env

  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    container_name: mongo-express
    links:
      - mongo
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    env_file: .env
```

with the following env file :

```
MONGODB_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root
MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=conwaysgame
MONGO_INITDB_USER=conway
MONGO_INITDB_PWD=password
MONGO_URL=mongodb://conway:password@mongo:27017/conwaysgame
ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=mongo
ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ENABLE_ADMIN=true
ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=root
ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=password
ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_USERNAME=admin
ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_PASSWORD=password
```

I tried connecting with studio 3T to the MONGO_INITDB_USER account with no success.
After further inspections i used MongoExpress to check the list of users and databases MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE was not created and neither was MONGO_INITDB_USER.
I tried renaming MONGO_INITDB_USER to MONGODB_INITDB_USER and MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE to MONGODB_INITDB_DATABASE with no success.

Comment: I have no clue how docker creates the users, but have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63754742/authentication-failure-while-trying-to-save-to-mongodb/63755470#63755470 Check existing users with `db.getSiblingDB('admin').getCollection('system.users').find()`

Comment: I did check users and no user was created except root